# How to round to n decimal places in Apache Derby JavaDB

Tags: derby

How does one round a given value to n decimal places in Apache Derby using SQL? It should be to the nearest decimal. The SQL round function is not supported in Apache Derby.

Comment: Do you mean, using SQL, or using Java? I think it is easiest to use the Java libraries for rounding and formatting numbers.

Comment: I need to use SQL.

Comment: What happens if you try `select  FLOOR(column + 0.5)`

Comment: Thank you Bryan this seems to have worked perfectly! Clever!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to round the number to two decimal places, you can change the number 2 below to any number of digit you want to round.

cast (@number as decimal(31,2))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Documentation says: When truncating trailing digits from a DECIMAL value, Derby rounds down.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cast (@number + 0.005 as decimal(31,2))
```

This should work as decimal always rounds down.